# Eager loaded model returns empty set for parent model property

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to eager load two models with their parent model. I get a null set for the relationship function though.

Here is how I am loading the models:

Master_Key controller (show method):

```
$master_keys = Version2015_Master_Key::with('version2015_question')->paginate(50);
            return view('masterkey/show',compact('master_keys'));
```

Response controller (show method):

```
$responses = Version2015_Response::with('version2015_question')->paginate(50);
         return view('response/show',compact('responses'));
```

I want to display master keys and responses alongside with the matching questions. 
Here is as snippet from my `show.blade.php` for the master key controller:

```
<table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>Ref Number</th>
          <th>Question</th>
          <th>Expected Response</th>
          <th>Additional Information</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach ($master_keys as $master_key)
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $master_key->question_num }} </td>
          <td>{{ $master_key->version2015_question }} </td>
          <td>{{ $master_key->expected_response }} </td>
          <td>{{ $master_key->additional_information }} </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </table>
```

The line `<td>{{ $master_key->version2015_question }} </td>` is the only one that tries to show data from the parent table. It actually should be `<td>{{ $master_key->version2015_question->question_text }} </td>` -> but when I try to do this it throws an error saying that I am trying to access a property from a non-object. And `<td>{{ $master_key->version2015_question }} </td>` returns an empty set. All the other properties return the expected data (since they belong to the master key model itself).

There are three models: `Version2015_Question`, `Version2015_Response` and `Version2015_Master_Key`.  They are all in the name space `app\version2015`. I am gonna post only two of them (since Response and Master Key have the same structure and same behavior):

Question Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Version2015_Question extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Version2015_questions';
    protected $primaryKey = 'question_num';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function version(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Version');
    }

    public function Version2015_responses(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Version2015\Version2015_Response','question_num','question_num');
    }

    public function version2015_master_keys(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Version2015\Version2015_Master_Key','question_num','question_num');
   }

    protected $fillable = ['question_num','question_text','version_id'];
}
```

Response Model:

```
namespace App\Version2015;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Encryptable;

class Version2015_Response extends Model
    {
        use Encryptable;
        protected $fillable = ['response','additional_information', 'question_num', 'vendor_id', 'label_id', 'group_id'];

        protected $encryptable = ['response','additonal_information'];

        protected $table = 'version2015_responses';

        public $timestamps = false;

        public function version2015_question(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Version2015\Version2015_Question','question_num','question_num');
     }

    public function vendor(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Vendor');
    }

    public function group(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
    }

    public function response_label(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Response_Label');
    }
}
```

I am not going to post the migrations because there's too much code in this post already. When I run `php artisan migrate` it works fine. When I create  `responses` and `master keys` there's no issue with the foreign keys referenced in the `questions` table. So I assume there's no problem in the database side. I believe it has something to do with the models and relationships. I've spent several hours reviewing the whole code and looking up other threads. I didn't come to any conclusion for why it doesn't pull the question data from the `questions` model. I am doing this kind of query with many other models in my application, but it only happens with those three - which happen to be the only ones in their own name space.

- - Update - -

Version2015_question model as @MarcoAurélioDeleu requested

```
namespace App\Version2015;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use App\Encryptable;

class Version2015_Master_Key extends Model
{
    use Encryptable;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'version2015_master_keys';

    protected $fillable = ['question_num','expected_response','group_id','label_id','additional_information'];

protected $encryptable = ['expected_response','additional_information'];

public function version2015_question(){
    //return $this->belongsTo('App\version2015\version2015_Question','question_num','question_num');
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Version2015\Version2015_Question');
    }

public function master_key_label(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Master_Key_Label');
}

public function group(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
}
}
```

Comment: What happens when you `dd($master_keys)`?

Comment: You didn't post the Version2015_Master_Key Model. Also, your Version2015_Response does not have a `version2015_question()` method, how would you load it `with()` that?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu this is what I get for "relations": ``        #relations: array:1 [▼
          "version2015_question" => null
        ] ``

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu I just addded the model. Check the update on my post. And yes, my Version2015_response does have a version2015_question() - double check it there pls

Comment: That is your problem.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu Sorry. I don't get it.

Comment: the value you pass to `with()` method must match the name of the method that creates the relationship between the models. For `Version2015_Response::with('version2015_question')` to work, your `Version2015_Response` class must have a method called `version2015_question()` that creates a relationship between the models.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu Yes, but that's what I was saying. It is right. I do have the methods there. Please double check the code. The methods match perfectly, and if they didn't Laravel would throw an error (I've made some tests).

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu I jsut submitted an answer to my own question. It took me a while to post it here but I found a solution in that same week when I opened this thread. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! All I had to do was to explicitly set which primary key Laravel should look for in the parent model since it is not following the convention "id" but "question_number".  I was doing this before but with an extra argument `return $this->belongsTo('App\version2015\version2015_Question','question_num','question_num');`, then I tried without any argument `return $this->belongsTo('App\version2015\version2015_Question');`. However, I should simply point what is the primary key in the parent table: `return $this->belongsTo('App\version2015\version2015_Question','question_num');`. Same thing for the other parent table `return $this->belongsTo('App\Master_Key_Label','label_id');`.

Besides that, the parent table doesn't need this explicit definition for their children as I was doing: `return $this->hasMany('App\version2015\version2015_Response','question_num','question_num');`. It only needs the child model name.

So, this is how my models look like now:

Question Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Version2015_Question extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Version2015_questions';
    protected $primaryKey = 'question_num';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function version(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Version');
    }

    public function Version2015_responses(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Version2015\Version2015_Response');
    }

    public function version2015_master_keys(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Version2015\Version2015_Master_Key');
   }

    protected $fillable = ['question_num','question_text','version_id'];
}
```

Response Model:

```
namespace App\Version2015;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Encryptable;

class Version2015_Response extends Model
    {
        use Encryptable;
        protected $fillable = ['response','additional_information', 'question_num', 'vendor_id', 'label_id', 'group_id'];

        protected $encryptable = ['response','additonal_information'];

        protected $table = 'version2015_responses';

        public $timestamps = false;

        public function version2015_question(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Version2015\Version2015_Question','question_num');
     }

    public function vendor(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Vendor');
    }

    public function group(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
    }

    public function response_label(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Response_Label', 'label_id');
    }
}
```

Same goes for Master Key model as in Response Key.

I also noticed another problem. For some reason I could not eager load the related models even with the right settings. 
My controllers had this:

```
  $responses = version2015_Response::with('version2015_question')
  ->where('label_id','=',$label->id)
  ->paginate(50);
```

Now I have to do this:

```
  $responses = version2015_Response::where('label_id','=',$label->id)
  ->paginate(50);
```

Well, with it all done everything works fine. I hope it helps other people with similar problems.